# Moving An Absolute Position Element Based Off Of Its Center

Tags: html, css

How would one move an absolute position element through CSS ideally by its center instead of its top left corner?

I currently have a circular element that I am adjusting via absolute positioning. I would like to move it based off of the center of the circle so that I can align it with a line on the background. The size of the circle is dynamic, and so is the background. Trying to get the red circle aligned to where the indigo meets the grey.

```
//Heres the code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4akwe208/4/

[image: Image For Reference]

Comment: please explain more :)

Comment: I currently have a circular element that I am adjust via absolute positioning. I would like to move it based off of the center of the circle so that I can align it with a line on the background. The size of the circle is dynamic, and so is the background. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can edit your explanation on your question, and maybe, image does some help with it

Comment: Please include the code you're using to render what you have already accomplished.

Comment: Do you have a fixed circle size? isn't it just top+width/2 or left +height/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do is to use CSS `transforms` property with the value `translate`.

```css
#your-div-id {
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

The value `-50%` controls X-axis, and `50%` is for the Y-axis

**PS:** *play around the values to get what you want*

check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for more details