# How to absolutely position an element based off of its center

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would one move an absolute position element through CSS ideally by its center instead of its top left corner?

I currently have a circular element that I am adjusting via absolute positioning. I would like to move it based off of the center of the circle so that I can align it with a line on the background. The size of the circle is dynamic, and so is the background. Trying to get the red circle aligned to where the indigo meets the grey.

```
//Heres the code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4akwe208/4/

Here's an image of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/912k6.png

Comment: Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143287/moving-an-absolute-position-element-based-off-of-its-center).

Comment: you want to get that arrow element to center?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `transforms` property with the value `translate`.

```css
#your-div-name {
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

The first value `-50%` controls X-axis, and `50%` is for the Y-axis

**PS:** *play around the values to get what you want. Either `px` or `%` values works

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `calc`

```css
#login-stage-goto-large {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(20vh - 28px); // (14vh + 6vh) - (58px / 2)
    left: 90vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, you want to get the red circle to the center where the indigo meets the grey colors. Therefore add the following changes to your code. This will make the circle center from left:0, right:0 and margin:auto. After that you can take the circle down by adding top attribute.

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 4.1rem;
margin: auto
```

```css
.background-p1 {
  z-index: -1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 4vh;
  background-color: #283593;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-p2 {
  z-index: -1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 16vh;
  background-color: #3949ab;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-p3 {
  z-index: -1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#login-stage-goto-large {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 2.2rem;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background-p1"></div>
  <div class="background-p2"></div>
  <div class="background-p3"></div>
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" id="login-stage-goto-large"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your above snippet with the solution, adding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    modPosition();
})
$(window).resize(function(){
    modPosition();
})
function modPosition(){
    var width = $('.background-p2').width();
  var padding = width-150;
    $('#login-stage-goto-large').css('left', padding);
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/4akwe208/33/**

You can find a function that cover all possible runtime modification of positioning.

you can edit the 150 value to another desired one.